# How to enable_shared_from_this of both parent and derived

Tags: c++, boost, smart-pointers

I have simple base and derived class that I want both have `shared_from_this()`.

This simple solution:

```
class foo : public enable_shared_from_this<foo> {
    void foo_do_it()
    {
        cout<<"foo::do_it\n";
    }
public:
    virtual function<void()> get_callback()
    {
        return boost::bind(&foo::foo_do_it,shared_from_this());
    }
    virtual ~foo() {};
};

class bar1 : public foo , public enable_shared_from_this<bar1> {
    using enable_shared_from_this<bar1>::shared_from_this;
    void bar1_do_it()
    {
        cout<<"foo::do_it\n";
    }
public:
    virtual function<void()> get_callback()
    {
        return boost::bind(&bar1::bar1_do_it,shared_from_this());
    }
};
```

Causes exception `tr1::bad_weak_ptr` in following code:

```
shared_ptr<foo> ptr(shared_ptr<foo>(new bar1));
function<void()> f=ptr->get_callback();
f();
```

So after "googling" I have found following solution:

```
class bar2 : public foo {
    void bar2_do_it()
    {
        cout<<"foo::do_it\n";
    }
    shared_ptr<bar2> shared_from_this()
    {
        return boost::static_pointer_cast<bar2>(foo::shared_from_this());
    }
public:
    virtual function<void()> get_callback()
    {
        return boost::bind(&bar2::bar2_do_it,shared_from_this());
    }
};
```

And now it works.

Is there any better and more convinient and correct way to `enable_shared_from_this` for both parent and child?

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Sorry, but there isn't.

The problem is that `shared_ptr<foo>` and `shared_ptr<bar1>` are different types. I don't understand everything that's going on under the hood, but I *think* that when the constructor returns and is assigned to a `shared_ptr<foo>`, the internal `weak_ptr<bar1>` sees that nothing is pointing to it (because only a `shared_ptr<bar1>` would increment the counter) and resets itself. When you call `bar1::shared_from_this` in `get_callback`, you get the exception because the internal `weak_ptr` isn't pointing to anything.

Essentially, `enable_shared_from_this` only seems to work transparently from a single class in a hierarchy. If you try [implementing it manually](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/smart_ptr/sp_techniques.html#from_this), the problem should become obvious.

Comment: I tried implementing it manually, and it's actually not that hard. In `My::SmartPointer<T>`, check if T is derived from `My::enableSmartFromThis`. If so, don't allocate a reference counter on the heap, but use the members of `My::enableSmartFromThis`. Now `My::GetSmartFromThis(this)` becomes trivial, it can convert `this` to a  `My::enableSmartFromThis*` and find the existing reference count. You can even check if you're trying to convert from Base to Derived when only Derived derives from `My::enableSmartFromThis`.

Answer (score 57):

The OP solution can be made more convenient by defining the following on the base class.

```
protected:
    template <typename Derived>
    std::shared_ptr<Derived> shared_from_base()
    {
        return std::static_pointer_cast<Derived>(shared_from_this());
    }
```

This can be made more convenient by placing it in a base class (for reuse).

```
#include <memory>

template <class Base>
class enable_shared_from_base
  : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Base>
{
protected:
    template <class Derived>
    std::shared_ptr<Derived> shared_from_base()
    {
        return std::static_pointer_cast<Derived>(shared_from_this());
    }
};
```

and then deriving from it as follows.

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

class foo : public enable_shared_from_base<foo> {
    void foo_do_it()
    {
        std::cout << "foo::do_it\n";
    }
public:
    virtual std::function<void()> get_callback()
    {
        return std::bind(&foo::foo_do_it, shared_from_base<foo>());
    }
};

class bar1 : public foo {
    void bar1_do_it()
    {
        std::cout << "bar1::do_it\n";
    }
public:
    virtual std::function<void()> get_callback() override
    {
        return std::bind(&bar1::bar1_do_it, shared_from_base<bar1>());
    }
};
```

Comment: That's pretty elegant. +1

Comment: `static_pointer_cast` don't support virtual inheritance.

Comment: The OP does not require it. However the same can be achieved as long as the type can be cast.

Answer (score 11):

A similar solution to @evoskuil that reduces boilerplate in derived classes should you want to implement a `shared_from_this()` function, resulting in the following code at the point of use in the class:

```
auto shared_from_this() {
    return shared_from(this);
}
```

This uses 'shim' functions outside of the class.  By doing it that way it also provides a clean way to do this for classes who's interface can't be modified but derive from `enable_shared_from_this` - e.g.

```
auto shared_that = shared_from(that);
```

Note: Use of `auto` for return types here will depend upon the age of your compiler.

Shim functions that could be placed in a library header:

```
template <typename Base>
inline std::shared_ptr<Base>
shared_from_base(std::enable_shared_from_this<Base>* base) 
{
    return base->shared_from_this();
}
template <typename Base>
inline std::shared_ptr<const Base>
shared_from_base(std::enable_shared_from_this<Base> const* base) 
{
    return base->shared_from_this();
}
template <typename That>
inline std::shared_ptr<That>
shared_from(That* that) 
{
    return std::static_pointer_cast<That>(shared_from_base(that));
}
```

The above code relies on the fact that the type passed to `shared_from(...)` inherits from `std::enable_shared_from_this<Base>` at some point in its ancestry.

Calling `shared_from_base` will figure out what type that ultimately was. Since we know that `That` inherits from `Base`, a static downcast can be made.

Probably there are some pathological corner cases with classes having type conversion operators.. but that's unlikely to occur in code not designed to break this.

**Example:**

```
struct base : public std::enable_shared_from_this<base> {};
struct derived : public base
{
    auto shared_from_this() {
        return shared_from(this);
    }
    // Can also provide a version for const:
    auto shared_from_this() const {
        return shared_from(this);
    }
    // Note that it is also possible to use shared_from(...) from
    // outside the class, e.g. 
    // auto sp = shared_from(that);
};
template <typename X>
struct derived_x : public derived
{
    auto shared_from_this() {
        return shared_from(this);
    }
};
```

**Compilation test:**

```
int main()
{
    auto pbase = std::make_shared<base>();
    auto pderived = std::make_shared<derived>();
    auto pderived_x = std::make_shared<derived_x<int> >();

    auto const& const_pderived = *pderived;
    const_pderived.shared_from_this();

    std::shared_ptr<base> test1 = pbase->shared_from_this();
    std::shared_ptr<derived> test2 = pderived->shared_from_this();
    std::shared_ptr<derived_x<int> > test3 = pderived_x->shared_from_this();

    return 0;
}
```

https://onlinegdb.com/SJWM5CYIG

**Prior solution** that I posted, kept to make the comments still make sense - this placed the functions in the base class which had some problems - particularly non-uniformity between the required implementation for 'normal' classes and template classes.
Additionally the implementation in the base class would need to be repeated for new class hierarchies which is not all that DRY.
Furthermore the base class function suffered from the possibility of misuse by supplying a base class pointer from a different object.  The newer scheme above avoids this entirely and the runtime assert(...) check goes.

Old implementation:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <memory>

class base : public std::enable_shared_from_this<base>
{
protected:   
    template <typename T>
    std::shared_ptr<T> shared_from(T* derived) {
        assert(this == derived);
        return std::static_pointer_cast<T>(shared_from_this());
    }
};

class derived : public base
{
public:
    auto shared_from_this() {
        return shared_from(this);
    }
};

template <typename X>
class derived_x : public derived
{
public:
    auto shared_from_this() {
        return this->template shared_from(this);
    }
};

int main()
{
    auto pbase = std::make_shared<base>();
    auto pderived = std::make_shared<derived>();
    auto pderived_x = std::make_shared<derived_x<int> >();

    std::shared_ptr<base> test1 = pbase->shared_from_this();
    std::shared_ptr<derived> test2 = pderived->shared_from_this();
    std::shared_ptr<derived_x<int> > test3 = pderived_x->shared_from_this();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why did you use `template` keyword in `derived_x`?

Comment: @Myon this is because shared_from is a template member function in the base class and it is being called from within a template class.  Without 'this' or 'template' keywords here it will fail to compile on compliant compilers.  Older version of MSVC would probably compile this fine.  

Without it the compiler will interpret the '<' symbol as a 'less than' operator.  See section 17.2.4 (page 312) in the current draft c++ standard doc: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4713.pdf,

Comment: @Myon actually came up with a better way of doing this that avoids the ugly template class non-uniformity entirely and also has a number of other positive side effects - see updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Quite easy; inherit `public shared_from_this` only in your base class. Implement an accessor in your derived class that casts to the appropriate type;

```
std::shared_ptr<Derived> shared() 
{
   return std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Derived>(Base::shared_from_this());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
template<class T>
class Base : public std::enable_shared_from_this<T> {
};

template<class T>
class Intermediate : public Base<T> {
};

class Derived : public Intermediate<Derived> {
  public:

  std::shared_ptr<Derived> getDerived() { return shared_from_this(); }
};
```

Comment: This is a good answer. You can make it the best answer of all if you find a way to make it work for hierarchies deeper than 1 level.

Comment: Autch, sorry, I put you on the wrong track. Your first solution was very good. Often hierarchies only have one level and then your previous solution is the one to go for me. I do not like your new solution. BTW, in your previous solution the getDerived function is not required, you can use `shared_from_this` directly. Finally, your previous version included the required headers which is always good.

Answer (score 0):

With c++23 deducing this, things become much easier. https://godbolt.org/z/j499WK58Y

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

struct new_enable_shared_from_this :
    public std::enable_shared_from_this<new_enable_shared_from_this> {
    
    template <typename Self>
    auto new_shared_from_this(this Self& self) {
        return std::static_pointer_cast<Self>(self.shared_from_this());
    }
};

class foo : public new_enable_shared_from_this {
    void foo_do_it()
    {
        cout<<"foo::do_it\n";
    }
public:
    virtual function<void()> get_callback()
    {
        return bind(&foo::foo_do_it,new_shared_from_this());
    }
    virtual ~foo() {};
};

class bar1 : public foo {
    void bar1_do_it()
    {
        cout<<"foo::do_it\n";
    }
public:
    virtual function<void()> get_callback()
    {
        return bind(&bar1::bar1_do_it,new_shared_from_this());
    }
};

int main() {
    auto pf = std::make_shared<foo>();
    pf->get_callback()();
    auto pb = std::make_shared<bar1>();
    pb->get_callback()();
}
```

This is the previous answer:

Well, I don't like virtual function. Virtual function is just for type erasing, but we don't need type erasing all the time. So, provide a mechanism for type erasing is enough. Here is an example that don't use virtual function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

template<typename derived>
class foo_imp {
    void foo_do_it()
    {
        cout<<"foo::do_it\n";
    }
public:
    function<void()> get_callback()
    {
        auto&& d = static_cast<derived&>(*this);
        return bind(&foo_imp::foo_do_it, d.shared_from_this());
    }
};

template<typename derived>
class bar_imp {
    void bar_do_it()
    {
        cout<<"bar::do_it\n";
    }
public:
    function<void()> get_callback()
    {
        auto&& d = static_cast<derived&>(*this);
        return bind(&bar_imp::bar_do_it, d.shared_from_this());
    }
};

struct foo : public foo_imp<foo>, public enable_shared_from_this<foo> {};
struct bar : public bar_imp<bar>, public enable_shared_from_this<bar> {};

struct v_foo {
    virtual function<void()> get_callback() = 0;
};

template <typename T>
std::shared_ptr<v_foo> convert(const std::shared_ptr<T>& st) {
    struct _ : public v_foo {
        _(const std::shared_ptr<T>& st) : _st{st} {}
        function<void()> get_callback() override {
            return _st->get_callback();
        }
        std::shared_ptr<T> _st;
    };
    return std::make_shared<_>(st);
}

int main() {
    auto sf = make_shared<bar>();
    sf->get_callback()();

    auto svf = convert(sf);
    svf->get_callback()();

    auto sb = make_shared<foo>();
    sb->get_callback()();

    auto svb = convert(sb);
    svb->get_callback()();
}
```