# Can I use the type of "this" as a template argument (inside a macro)?

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr

I currently have this:

```
#define THIS(T) (boost::static_pointer_cast<T>(shared_from_this()))
```

The macro is used in a method like this:

```
void Derived::run() {
    do_something_with_a_shared_ptr(THIS(Derived));
}
```

That's all well and good, but I'd like to eliminate `(Derived)` and have:

```
void Derived::run() {
    do_something_with_a_shared_ptr(THIS);
}
```

Is this possible?

Alternatively, is there a better way to have convenient access to a `shared_ptr` to `this`, in a class derived (indirectly) from `boost::enable_shared_from_this`? [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/657155/how-to-enable-shared-from-this-of-both-parend-and-derived) seems to indicate the answer to this is no.

The class hierarchy looks like this:

```
class Base: public boost::enable_shared_from_this<Base> {
    ...
}

class Derived: public Base {
    ...
    void run();
    ...
}

void do_something_with_a_shared_ptr(boost::shared_ptr<Derived>);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not exactly an answer to your question, but have you considered using a member function instead of a macro? I usually do something like:

```
boost::shared_ptr< Derived > shared_this()
{
     return boost::static_pointer_cast<Derived>(shared_from_this());
}
boost::shared_ptr< Derived const > shared_this() const
{
     return boost::static_pointer_cast<Derived const>(shared_from_this());
}
```

Comment: Note that if you are usign C++11, you could do something based on decltype and this.

Comment: Very interesting to read about decltype and C++11, thanks. Your answer certainly beats using a macro, though I would need to repeat this code if I had several Derived classes (which I do). These methods could be included in another class from which Derived inherits but then we have multiple inheritance. Is this the way to go or is there something else that could be done with templates?

Comment: You should be able to make `shared_this` templated on `Derived`, declare it once in `Base` and use it from each of your different `Derived` classes.

Comment: Excellent, that works brilliantly. From `THIS(Derived)` I now have `shared_this<Derived>()` which feels a lot more like C++, and hopefully with `decltype` this can be made even simpler. Thanks very much, I've learnt a lot here.

Comment: Just figured you could automatically get the type even in C++03 if you template shared_this on Derived and take a Derived/Derived const pointer as an argument, to which you would pass this. Resulting in `shared_this( this );` which may seem better to you, I'd rather stick with explicitly stating the type.

Comment: So you can, and I think I prefer the `shared_this(this)` version. It looks less easy to get wrong. The `shared_this<Derived>()` version is open to putting, say `shared_this<OtherDerived>()` and ending up with a subtle bug.

Comment: There are no subtle bugs, the code wont compile if OtherDerived is not derived from Base. You could either get a shared pointer to a more derived class, which would be fine; or to a less derived class that could be a problem but such problem will itself show up as a compilation error as well.