# Ambiguity while referencing privately inherited method from of base class

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, overload-resolution

I have a base class and child class. I want `shared_from_this` to return `shared_ptr` to the object in which it is invoked. So if `shared_from_this()` is called on child it should return a `shared_ptr` to child and same way for base. Below is my sample program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class parent : private std::enable_shared_from_this<parent> {
public:
  int a;
  parent() : a(1) { }
  virtual void  f(){
    auto self = shared_from_this();
    std::cout << "Parent is " << self->a << std::endl;
  }
};

class child : public parent, private std::enable_shared_from_this<child> {
public:
  int a;
  child() : a (2) { }
  virtual void  f() {
    auto self = shared_from_this();
    std::cout << "Child is " << self->a << std::endl;
  }
};

int main(){
  auto p = std::make_shared<parent>();
  auto c = std::make_shared<child>();
  p->f();
  c->f();
}
```

Since `enable_shared_from_this` is privately inherited, `shared_from_this()` method for both the classes should be private to themselves hence there shouldn't be any collision/ambiguity. However I get following error while compiling.

```
[root@archlinux cpp]# clang++ -g stackoverflow_shared_from_this.cpp
stackoverflow_shared_from_this.cpp:19:17: error: member 'shared_from_this' found in multiple base classes of different types
    auto self = shared_from_this();
                ^
/usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.1.0/../../../../include/c++/11.1.0/bits/shared_ptr.h:807:7: note: member found by ambiguous name lookup
      shared_from_this()
      ^
/usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.1.0/../../../../include/c++/11.1.0/bits/shared_ptr.h:807:7: note: member found by ambiguous name lookup
1 error generated.
[root@archlinux cpp]#
```

Can somebody please explain why am I getting this ambiguity error ? What part of my explanation above is incorrect.

Comment: Accessibility doesn't exclude a function from the overload resolution set, by language design.

Comment: The member functions inherited from `private` bases participate in overload resolution, just as they would with `public` or `protected` inheritance.   There is ambiguity in your case, because two inherited bases have a `private`  member function `shared_from_this()` with the same signature (no arguments).   The check of `private` access only happens if an unambiguous match is found, which isn't true for your example.     In any event, from C++17, `public` inheritance from `std::enable_shared_from_this` is mandatory.

Comment: If you get it to compile it won't work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/657155/how-to-enable-shared-from-this-of-both-parent-and-derived plus you need to publicly inherit from `enable_shared_from_this` or it won't work

Comment: Thanks a lot @Evg. I have got the reason for breakage.