# C++ combine maps of enums

Tags: c++, c++11, enums

Let's imagine I have some class hierarchy for a game. Like this:
**PhysicalObject** is parent of **BaseUnit** is parent of **BaseArcher** and so on...
And each hierarchy level adds its own stats.

Any PhysicalObject - has speed and size.
Any BaseUnit - hit points.

I want it to be used as enums, so:

```
enum class PhysicalObjectStats { speed, size };
enum class BaseUnitStats { hitpoints };
```

Of course, BaseArcher must include stats of PhysicalObject and BaseUnit.
How to make such an architecture?
I've tried to implement it in such a simple way, using just map and dynamic polymorphism, but it doesn't compile (with a good reason, honestly):

https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8496247abd3e6f41

Also, I've tried to create a specific StatsHolder class and it works, but looks awful in all possible use-cases (setting and getting values). Actually, I cannot get value outside of class without down-casting:

https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/46f4f4aec6a22c57

In addition, my stats may be not only *int*, but also *bool* and some other types. I tried to use std::variant for them and it works fine, but I don't want to think about it, using "GetStats()" method. So, ideally I want to have such an interface:

```
std::shared_ptr<PhysicalObject> unit = std::make_shared<BaseUnit>();
unit->SetValue<int>(PhysicalObjectStats::speed);
std::cout << unit->GetValue<bool>(BaseUnitStats::HasArmor);
```

And this makes the task even more difficult. Any suggestions of how it may be done in a good way?

Comment: Have you considered using an [Entity Component System architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_component_system)? A well-known C++ library implementing this is [EnTT](https://github.com/skypjack/entt).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the point of map and enum whereas regular member seems to do the job:

```
struct PhysicalObject
{
    int speed = 0;
    int size = 0;
};
struct BaseUnitStats : PhysicalObject
{
// or composition:
// physicalObject PhysicalObject;
    int hitpoints = 0;
};
```

For your `StatsHolder` class:

```
template<class StatsEnum>
struct StatsHolder
{
    void SetStats(StatsEnum stat, int value) { stats[stat] = value; }
    int GetStats(StatsEnum stat) const { return stats.at(stat); }
private:
    std::map<StatsEnum, int> stats;
};
```

Derived classes have to use `using`:

```
struct BaseUnit : PhysicalObject, StatsHolder<BaseUnitStats> {
    using PhysicalObject::GetStats;
    using StatsHolder<BaseUnitStats>::GetStats;
    using PhysicalObject::SetStats;
    using StatsHolder<BaseUnitStats>::SetStats;

    BaseUnit() { SetStats(BaseUnitStats::hitpoints, 300); }
};
```

[Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/46b0eaf4d316a37f)

Comment: About regular members:
As you understand, there may be a lot of stats, let's say - dozens. And for each of them I have to provide a setter and getter at least. Also - perfectly - methods like "OnSetSpeed(int oldValue)". So every my class will be overfilled with such simple and monotone methods. Using map of enums makes it possible to use only one "control method". That's my main thought here.

Comment: And, also, thanks for your suggestion with "using"! It works great, however it needs to be used as an object itself, right? So, I have to implement something to cast ptr of PhysicalObject into something. For example, as it is described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/32172486/10038365 .

Comment: If you have a `PhysicalObject` pointer and use is as `BaseUnit`, you have indeed to cast it in some way. But it seems unrelated to your problem with enum/map.

Comment: *"I have to provide a setter and getter"* if just that public member would be enough. *"methods like `OnSetSpeed(int oldValue)`."* here a class `property<T>` with a getter/setter/OnSet signal seems to do the job too.