# Inheriting both class template and the template paraemeter

Tags: c++, class, templates, inheritance, c++20

Suppose we have the following template class, inspired by `std::shared_ptr` (ignore bad memory management for simplicity):

```
template <class C> class shared_class {
public:
  const shared_class& operator=(const shared_class& rhs) {
    ptr = rhs.ptr;
    refs[ptr] += 1;
    return *this;
  }

  C* data() { return ptr; }

protected:
  shared_class() {
    if (ptr == nullptr)
      ptr = new C;
    refs[ptr] = 1;
  }
  shared_class(const shared_class& other) {
    ptr = other.ptr;
    refs[ptr] += 1;
  }
  ~shared_class() {
    if ((refs[ptr] -= 1) == 0) {
      refs.erase(ptr);
      delete ptr;
    }
  }

private:
  static std::unordered_map<C*, size_t> refs;
  C* ptr = nullptr;
};

template <class C> std::unordered_map<C*, size_t> shared_class<C>::refs = {};
```

I would like to use it in the following way:

```
class A_data {
protected:
  int foo = 50;

  friend class A;
  friend class shared_class<A_data>;
};

class A : protected shared_class<A_data> {
public:
  void foo(int f) { data()->foo = h; }
  int foo() { return data()->foo; }
};

using namespace std;

int main(){
  A a;
  A b = a;
  a.foo(40);
  cout << b.foo(); // 40
}
```

This works well, but  now suppose I want to create a class that inherits `A`, but also inherits its data, such as this:

```
class B_data : public A_data {
  int bar = 100;

  friend class B;
  friend class shared_class<B_data> // Probably wrong
};

class B : public A {
  int bar() {
    return data()->bar(); // Error: no member 'bar' in A_data
  }
}
```

This is a problem, because the constructor in `shared_class` only knows how to allocate `A_data`. It seems to me that I am only able to decide on one form of inheritence: either I inherit the template class like above, or I can inherit a different `shared_class` template, like this:

```
class B_data : public A_data {
  int bar = 100;

  friend class B;
  friend class shared_class<B_data> // Now it's not wrong
};

class B : public shared_class<B_data> {
  int bar() {
    return data()->bar(); // Now it will work
  }
}
```

While this works, I lose relation to the `A` class, and am now unable to do use `A::foo`, forcing me to define it in `B`:

```
class B : public shared_class<B_data> {
  void foo(int f) { data()->foo = h; }
  int foo() { return data()->foo; }
  int bar() { return data()->bar(); }
}
```

Is there a (relatively elegant) way to make this work as though `B` inherits `A` while simultaneously `B_data` inherits `A_data`?

Comment: Make `A` a template too that determines the real type of the data? You could default the template parameter to `A_data` to be able to refer to `A<A_data>` as `A`...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72526030/17890874 Maybe you can look my previous answer.

Comment: @fabian While this is definitely a solution I haven't thought of, won't I be forced to expose the implementation in the header of the base class, even if it doesn't use the template beyond the inheritence? EDIT: No, I am not. I tested it. This works well, then.